# Pairwise Testing Combination generator in Python

Tags: python, testing, combinations

I am trying pairwise testing and wanted Python based pairwise testing tool. I already tried AllPairs(http://pypi.python.org/pypi/AllPairs/2.0.1). It has bug when I give 10 entries in a Column. Currently using Microsoft PICT to generate pairwise combination.

Is there any tool in Python that generates pairwise combinations for large arrays?

Bug in AllPairs
If I give this

```
parameters = [ [ "Brand X", "Brand Y","Brand A","Brand B","Brand C","Brand D" ]
             , [ "98", "NT", "2000", "XP"]
             , [ "Internal", "Modem","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M" ]
             , [ "Salaried", "Hourly", "Part-Time", "Contr.","AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II" ]
             , [ 6, 10, 15, 30, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140 ]
             ]
```

Output is

```
Brand X count is 16
Brand Y count is 122
Brand A count is 16
Brand B count is 16
Brand C count is 16
Brand D count is 15
```

for this

```
parameters = [ [ "Brand X", "Brand Y","Brand A","Brand B","Brand C","Brand D" ]
             , [ "98", "NT", "2000", "XP"]
             , [ "Internal", "Modem" ]
             , [ "Salaried", "Hourly", "Part-Time", "Contr." ]
             , [ 6, 10, 15, 30, 60 ]
             ]
```

output is

```
Brand X count is 5
Brand Y count is 5
Brand A count is 5
Brand B count is 5
Brand C count is 5
Brand D count is 6
```

I think, it is not correct working for larger array.

Comment: Do you want to pair every element of one array with every element of another array? If not, please give a reference to the method you are after.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the "bug"?

Comment: @JanneKarila I've used itertools. For my data, using product will require 57K cases. So want to go for pairwise that will give 300 cases.

Comment: @Rajasankar: 57,000 cases is not that much information. You can't just randomly sample cases out of the ones generated by `itertools.product()`?

Comment: @JoelCornett taking random cases from that combination data is called pairwise. I dont want to reinvent the wheel if there is an python module exists.

Comment: If you're still interested, I went back and rewrote the pairwise combinations generator so it generates exactly `m * n` items, where `m` and `n` are the lengths of the two largest input lists. In other words, I got it to work.

Comment: @JoelCornett Sure. Can you post that answer. I am still looking for that in Python code. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajasankar: I posted it on codereview. Here is the link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/14120/10285

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
from itertools import chain, combinations, product

def pairwiseGen(*sequences):
    unseen = set(chain.from_iterable(product(*i) for i in combinations(sequences, 2)))
    for path in product(*sequences):
        common_pairs = set(combinations(path, 2)) & unseen
        if common_pairs:
            yield path
            unseen.difference_update(common_pairs)
```

Usage (using the `parameters` list you defined in your question):

```
>>> pairs = list(pairwiseGen(*parameters))
>>> len(pairs)
846
```

I think there is still some room for optimization (the above generator yielded slightly more results than were expected), but I think you'll agree that it's *much* shorter than using the cartesian product:

```
>>> all_possible = list(product(*parameters))
>>> len(all_possible)
60480
```

Comment: Please try Microsoft PICT tool to get the example output. also look into this http://www.pairwise.org/

Comment: @Rajasankar: You are right, this is not the problem that I thought it was. I was able to write a generator that yields pairwise sets of items from 3 sequences (trying to generalize it to process more). Would you like me to post it?

Comment: Yes, there is still room for optimization. Result should between 100 to 200. You can also check the orthogonal array for more info.

Comment: Shouldn't  60480 read 60840?  6 * 4 * 15 * 13 * 13  =  60840

Answer (score 4):

What about using [allpairspy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/allpairspy)? It is a fork of [AllPairs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AllPairs/2.0.1) with more functionality (probably bug fixes) and documentation. The [basic usage sample code](https://github.com/thombashi/allpairspy#basic-usage) adjusted to your parameters returns 200 5-tuples:

```
from allpairspy import AllPairs

parameters = [
    [ "Brand X", "Brand Y","Brand A","Brand B","Brand C","Brand D" ],
    [ "98", "NT", "2000", "XP"],
    [ "Internal", "Modem","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M" ],
    [ "Salaried", "Hourly", "Part-Time", "Contr.","AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II" ],
    [ 6, 10, 15, 30, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140 ]
]

print("PAIRWISE:")
for i, pairs in enumerate(AllPairs(parameters)):
    print("{:2d}: {}".format(i, pairs))
```

If you want to test Python code or with a pytest based test framework you can [integrate allpairspy with pytest via its test parametrization feature](https://github.com/thombashi/allpairspy#parameterized-testing-with-pairwise-by-using-pytest).

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** AllPairs is returning a valid pairwise test set even though the distribution of Brand and Windows Version are uneven.

**Example**

Here is your example:

```
Brand : Brand X, Brand Y, Brand A, Brand B, Brand C, Brand D
Version : 98, NT, 2000, XP
Network : Internal, Modem, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M
Wage : Salaried, Hourly, Part-Time, Contr., AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF, GG, HH, II
Time : 6, 10, 15, 30, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140
```

**Validity:**

If you check, you'll find both PICT and AllPairs contain all 993 2-tuples. Meaning both PICT and AllPairs return valid sets.

The total number of 2-tuples from above example is:

```
6*4 + 6*15 + 6*13 + 6*13 + 4*15 + 4*13 + 4*13 + 15*13 + 15*13 + 13*13 = 993
```

**Performance:**

The typical number of test cases is O(nm) where n and m are the two largest parameters. In this case: 15*13 = 195 is the absolute minimum number of test sets.

AllPairs returns 200 5-tuples

PICT returns 206 5-tuples

So both PICT and AllPairs return close to the minimum number to test sets.

**Distribution**:

What Raj pointed out is that AllPairs returns an unevenly distributed test set.

Brand:

```
Brand A : 16
Brand B : 16
Brand C : 16
Brand D : 15
Brand X : 16
Brand Y : 122
```

Version:

```
98 : 155
2000 : 15
NT : 16
XP : 15
```

PICT returns a more evenly distributed test set

Brand:

```
Brand A : 26
Brand B : 32
Brand C : 40
Brand D : 35
Brand X : 40
Brand Y : 33
```

Version:

```
98 : 48
2000 : 55
NT : 52
XP : 51
```

**Explanation**

The reason why an uneven distribution for Brand and Version is still valid is that these two fields have the lowest cardinality (6 and 4). So AllPairs seems to be filling the 5-tuples needed to get all pairs of Network and Wage with lots of `Brand Y` and `Windows 98`

Here is the cardinality of each field:

```
Brand : 6
Version : 4
Network : 15
Wage : 13
Time : 13
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created a wrapper around the MS pict implementation, this might be useful for you. Obviously has dependency, but saves recreating the wheel.

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess


def all_pairs(*sequence):
    """
    Calculate the all pairs testing sequence from the Microsoft PICT all pairs application
    that is compiled from: https://github.com/Microsoft/pict

    >>> Type = ['Single', 'Span', 'Stripe', 'Mirror', 'RAID-5']
    >>> Size = [10, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 40000]
    >>> Format_method = ['Quick', 'Slow']
    >>> File_system = ['FAT', 'FAT32', 'NTFS']
    >>> Cluster_size = [512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536]
    >>> Compression = ['On', 'Off']
    >>> combinations = all_pairs(Type, Size, Format_method, File_system, Cluster_size, Compression)
    >>> assert len(combinations) == 56
    """
    exe = '/opt/pict/bin/pict'
    assert os.path.exists(exe), 'Make sure you have install the PICT executable to: {}'.format(exe)
    assert len(sequence) > 0
    for s in sequence:
        assert isinstance(s, list)
        assert len(s) > 0

    # create input file
    lines = list()
    for i, s in enumerate(sequence):
        seq = ', '.join([str(r) for r in range(len(s))])
        new_line = '{}: {}'.format(i, seq)
        lines.append(new_line)

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as tmp:
        tmp.write(os.linesep.join(lines))
        tmp.flush()
        result = subprocess.check_output([exe, tmp.name])

    options = list()
    for line in result.split(os.linesep)[1:]:  # skip the header
        if len(line) == 0:
            continue
        indices = [int(i) for i in line.split('\t')]
        options.append([s[i] for s, i in zip(sequence, indices)])
    return options
```